# Print HTML dynamically on a page via PHP based on Condition

Tags: php

I want to print a section of a table if the data is available in JSON file for it. And if the data is not there and it shouldn't do anything.

So, far what I am doing is as below. Checking is the `account_type` is `parent` and then generate the table rows with corresponding data.

```
         <?php
               $str = file_get_contents('test.json');

               $json = json_decode($str, true);
               $parent= strtr('<tr>
                 <td colspan="2" style="color:#263a80;font-size:19px;padding-bottom:20px;padding-top:20px">Parent Information</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td style="width:30%;font-weight:700;padding-bottom:10px">First Name</td>
                 <td>@fname</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td style="width:30%;font-weight:700;padding-bottom:10px">Last Name</td>
                 <td>@lname</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td style="width:30%;font-weight:700;padding-bottom:10px">Mobile Number</td>
                 <td>@mobile</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td style="width:30%;font-weight:700;padding-bottom:10px">Email</td>
                 <td><a @email target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">@email</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td style="width:30%;font-weight:700;padding-bottom:10px">Country</td>
                 <td>@country</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td style="width:30%;font-weight:700;padding-bottom:10px">State</td>
                 <td>@state</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td style="width:30%;font-weight:700;padding-bottom:10px">City</td>
                 <td>@city</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td style="width:30%;font-weight:700;padding-bottom:10px">Postal Code</td>
                 <td>@pcode</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td style="width:30%;font-weight:700;padding-bottom:10px">Full Home Address</td>
                 <td>@address</td>
              </tr>', ["@fname"=>$json["json"]["register_session_1"]["first_name"],
                       "@lname"=>$json["json"]["register_session_1"]["last_name"],
                       "@mobile"=>$json["json"]["register_session_1"]["mobile"],
                       "@email"=>$json["json"]["register_session_1"]["email"],
                       "@country"=>$json["json"]["register_session_1"]["country"],
                       "@state"=>$json["json"]["register_session_1"]["state_online"],
                       "@city"=>$json["json"]["register_session_1"]["city"],
                       "@pcode"=>$json["json"]["register_session_1"]["postal_code"],
                       "@address"=>$json["json"]["register_session_1"]["address"]
                       ]);

              if ($json["json"]["register_session_1"]["account_type"]==="parent"){
                 echo $parent;                  
              }
              else {
                 echo "hahahah";
              }
              ?>
```

Problem is that it printing the table data anyway. I don't know what I am doing wrong. The if-else condition is not working.

I have this code and I can't seem to figure out why. I have added this code in between the `<table></table>` tag.

Comment: Print your `$json["json"]["register_session_1"]["account_type"]` and check if it's equal to `parent`. Then try remove `===` identical operator and use `==`

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: What's your `$json["json"]["register_session_1"]["account_type"]` content?

Comment: Currently it is set to "none"

Comment: Can you provide an example of the json file

Comment: Here: https://paste.ee/p/qcI3F But I don't think it is related to that. Because the table rows that the above code is printing has the data I want to print from the JSON. The only issue is that it not printing based on condition.

Comment: can you do a print_r for $json, we need to see whats inside $json.

Comment: `print_r` output: https://paste.ee/p/yjXSG

Comment: can you say what 'does not work' mean ??? this works on  my box, but produces (per your code) an invalid <a> tag for the email field. you probably meant `<a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">@email</a>`

Comment: Does not work mean that I want to print the table data only when the "account_type" is set to "parent" otherwise it shouldn't generate anything for the table ie blank table. But now what is happening is that, it is printing the table regardless of the condition.

Comment: works for me. When i change account_type to "parent" in your sample json, and run, it echoes the invalid html (per previous comment), and if i set it to "parEnt", lt laughs at me.

Comment: Your code should work, I recreated it and it works on my end. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2570a6cdea75b11bb2543633600859d469a9c44e

Comment: For me works too

Comment: Yeah, it is working now. It is working on the web server but not on command line. I wasn't running it on web server before...just from the command line. Thanks to all and sorry.

Comment: Try to check what you receive on $json["json"]["register_session_1"]["account_type"]. Probably there is typo on parent value since you are using identical operator like @YvesLeBorg said (eg. parEnt) or the value have white space